# Как усыпить текущий поток с возможностью возобновления из другого потока в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qt-faq

Имеется поток, который иногда засыпает(`QThread::sleep`) на довольно продолжительное время (около 5 секунд). Если пользователь закрывает программу, то основной поток пытается завершить уснувший, и ожидает его действительного завершения с помощью функции `QThread::wait`. Но 5 секунд - достаточно продолжительное время, чтобы пользователь занервничал. В связи с этим вопрос: как разбудить поток, который внутри себя вызвал функцию `QThread::sleep`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt не предоставляет средств для пробуждения спящего потока. Но вместо этого можно использовать класс `QWaitCondition` с некоторой доработкой. Напишем для этого специальный класс.

WakeableSleep.h:

```
#ifndef WAKEABLESLEEP_H
#define WAKEABLESLEEP_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QWaitCondition>
/**
 * @brief Класс, который позволяет временно усыпить поток с возможностью пробуждения из другого потока.
 *
 * Класс можно создать в любом потоке. При вызове метода \ref sleep поток приостанавливается
 * на время, переданное с параметром. При вызове метода \ref wake из другого потока целевой
 * поток возобновляет выполнение независимо от истекшего времени.
 * \threadsafe
 */
class WakeableSleep : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit WakeableSleep(QObject *parent = 0);
    /**
     * @brief Усыпить текущий поток на milleseconds миллисекунд.
     * @param milliseconds Время сна.
     */
    void sleep(quint32 milliseconds);
    /**
     * @brief wake Пробудить целевой поток из другого потока.
     */
    void wake();
private:
    QMutex mutex;
    QWaitCondition waitCondition;
};
#endif // WAKEABLESLEEP_H
```

WakeableSleep.cpp:

```
#include "wakeablesleep.h"
WakeableSleep::WakeableSleep(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent){}

void WakeableSleep::sleep(quint32 milliseconds)
{
    mutex.lock();
    waitCondition.wait(&mutex, milliseconds);
    mutex.unlock();
}

void WakeableSleep::wake()
{
    mutex.lock();
    waitCondition.wakeAll();
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

Теперь вместо метода `QThread::sleep` можно использовать методы этого класса следующим образом:

```
WakeableSleep sleeper;
void Thread1()
{
    sleeper.wake();
}
void Thread2()
{
    sleeper.sleep(5000);
}
```